# Downstream job to use the same build number and subversion revision as the upstream job in Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I have seen some duplicate questions but the answers didn't seem to help. The following is what I need: I have the upstream Job A and its downstream Job B. I use parameterized trigger plugin to kick off Job B once Job A finishes successfully.

I want the kicked off Job B to have the same build number and use the same SVN revision which Job A used to simplify things (Both jobs use separate workspaces BTW.)

Under Job A, I checked the "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" and added the subversion revision and current build parameters to the parameters for Job B when stable.

Under Job B, I checked the "This build is parameterized"  and used SVN_REVISION as a string parameter with default HEAD; and BUILD_NUMBER as a run parameter of Job A. Under SCM, for SVN url, I entered: http:// svn-path-here/trunk@$SVN_REVISION

Doing this always pulls the HEAD and uses different build number. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick web search reveals:

- With the parametrized build trigger, you need to use a "peg revision" in the SVN URL. E.g. `.../repository/trunk@${SVN_REVISION}`
- Or you can use [Tracking SVN plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tracking+SVN+Plugin).

See [this thread](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/What-is-the-correct-use-of-the-quot-Subversion-revision-quot-option-for-the-quot-Trigger-parameteriz-td3298054.html).